# How to transfer Microsoft Photo Person tags to 'normal file tags'?

Tags: metadata

How to transfer Microsoft Photo Person tags to 'normal file tags'?

For instance, I found a program called "TagThatPhoto" that has a video about MS Photo Gallery that says it can transfer person tags. Any experience with that program?

Comment: Some clarification on what you mean by "normal file tags" would be needed.